# Handle load time of big JSON for autocomplete on the server side

Tags: python, rest, http

Hello I have an app that have autocomplete suggestions for the user based on input in the search bar.

I use a package named [fast_autocomplete](https://pypi.org/project/fast-autocomplete/) which works great but I have a problem that each time I want to use the prediction I have to load 50MB of JSON data that I mad for the autocomplete (500K records).
While running it on a server side loading, parsing and sending back the data is quite slow for what you would except for autocomplete functionality. It less than a second and right now (testing locally) its takes few seconds.

Checking the issue it seems that it takes a lot of time to load the 50MB JSON for each request. Loading the data and building the autocomplete object each time a new request comes in is a waste of time.

For that I wondered if there is a way to keep the object loaded alive all the time and when a new HTTP request comes in the JSON is already loaded.
How big sites like Amazon, Ebay, Google makes there autocomplete so fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're loading your data for *every* request despite that data staying the same for each user. Why not cache that data? or store it outside of your request handler's scope?

```
auto_complete_data = open("...").read()

@route('/autocomplete')
def autocomplete():
  # keep reusing the `auto_complete_data`
```

Comment: thanks! I have not thought about it, shame on me... working great! thanks a lot.